# How can you query PFAnalytics information on parse.com?

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform

Parse.com provides a pretty handy tool for tracking analytical data from your apps.  The methods for posting said data are quite clearly defined.  There is an option to view that data in your application dashboard, with limited filtering.  You can also export the data into a CSV file from the dashboard.

Is there a way to 'GET' that data programmatically versus having to manually dump the CSV?

Comment: Thanks @Fosco. Bummer to hear, especially considering that the dashboard page does just that...  As an aside, can you shed any light on the recent outages?  Are these fundamental issues being identified or just a confluence of unfortunate events?

Comment: We posted a detailed postmortem just a little while ago: http://status.parse.com/incidents/3l5ksc81q8fk

Comment: Thanks again @Fosco.  Best of luck getting it sorted... we are definitely rooting for you guys!  Love the service, but these growing pains this year have been tough to stomach.